# update panel not working in user control

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am fixing issues in a project where I was not able to figure out a solution for the below problem.

There are multiple user controls in Main.aspx page. First one is header.ascx which is added directly in .aspx page. and the others are added dynamically from Page_Init event. Basing on the hyperlink clicked from the menu on the left side of the main page, the respective user control is displayed.

Now, If I try to add script-manager/update panel inside any of the dynamic user controls, the respective user control page throws error.

I have noticed that the header.ascx control is using scriptmanager. Is it creating the problem? How to handle this kind of issue? Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests you have SciptManagers in your user controls.  You can only have one ScriptManager per page, which I'm guessing is the error message you're getting.

Put the ScriptManager in the aspx page, not user controls.  If you need to reference the ScriptManager in the user controls you can either use a [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) or call `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page)` in the codebehind.

Comment: If I try to remove the ScriptManager in Header.ascx the main page is not at all loading. This the code used for that: 
<asp:ScriptManager id="scManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true"
                            AsyncPostBackTimeout="6000" >
</asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: Move it to the aspx page.  It needs to appear in the markup before any controls that need it, so stick it right at the top inside the `<form>` tag.  Please post more descriptive error messages so we have a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: I did all these things, but still not working. I guess the problem is with the header user control code.. I need to look into that code and will let you know... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually setting the IDs of the controls you are dynamically adding? You might need to.

Comment: I did that. But the problem is when try to click any checkbox or anything inside the user control, the page throws error.

Comment: @Sunny, did you fix the issue. I have similar kind of problem/